# PHP login script 404 error

Tags: php, authentication, http-status-code-404

I used a login script tutorial here: http://www.astahost.com/info/tilltf-simple-login-script-simple-secure-login-script.html and when I clocked login, there was a 404. When i went back, I was logged in. I followed the the tutorial exactly as it said. Any idea why it is going to this weird page?

```
    <?php

session_start();
require_once 'database.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){

echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user'];

?>

<form name="logout" method="post" action="logout.php">

<input type="submit" name="logout" id="logout" value="Logout">

</form>

<br /><form name="news" method="post" action="news.php">

 <input type="submit" name="news" id="news" value="News">

</form>

<?php

}

elseif(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){

echo"Welcome ".$_SESSION['admin'];

echo"<br><br>You are logged in as an Admin";

?>

<form name="logout" method="post" action="logout.php">

<input type="submit" name="logout" id="logout" value="Logout">

</form>



</form>

<?php

}else{

?>

<form name="login_form" method="post" action="login2.php">

 <label>

 <input name="user" type="text" id="user">ID<br />

 <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass">Password<br />

 </label>

 <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" action="index.php" value="Login">

 </label>

 </p>

</form>

<form name="Register" method="post" action="reg.php">

 <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register">

</form><br />

<form name="news" method="post" action="news.php">

 <input type="submit" name="news" id="news" value="News">

</form>

<?php

 }

 ?>
```

Comment: My bet: it does a post-redirect-get, and the final call to `header("Location: someplace.php")` points to a non-existent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glancing at the code you linked to, I noticed login2.php tries to redirect to Index.php in some cases, but to index.php (lowercase i) in other cases. It should be lowercase in both places. That might be the cause of your 404.

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial has a couple header redirects:

```
header("location:Index.php");
```

and

```
header("location:index.php");
```

Make sure they're not supposed to be pointing to the same file, and make sure that file exists. It's logging you in, and then trying to redirect you to a file it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your type of server, this might cause problems:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($queryN) == 1) {

    $resultN = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryN);                   

    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user']; 

    header("location:Index.php");    

}
```

Specifically because the `I` in `Index.php` is capitalized, while all other references to the file utilize a lowercase `i`.

Also, this code is TERRIBLY formatted... but alas that's a different problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the code at the link you provided, I see a likely cause.  At the end of the login processing script, there's a call to `header()` which redirects back to the index page.  One of them has different casing, and many web servers are case-sensitive by default:

```
header("location:index.php");
header("location:Index.php");
```

I'm guessing the lower case `index.php` is the correct one, so update your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

just an added warning: the linked example has a serious security hole along these lines

```
$escaped_username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
# make a md5 password.
$md5_password = md5($_POST['pass']);
$queryN = mysql_query("select * from user where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$md5_password."' AND level='1'");
```

`$escaped_username` is generated correctly, but the sql query still uses `$username`. this opens  up the possibility to inject sql statements. be sure to change it.